# How to WhiteList with before_filter, by removing certain controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm wondering if there is a way to whitelist controller authentication using before_filter, also excluding the ones that you may want. Something like that in application controller :

```
before_filter :authenticate_user!, :except_controller => :home
```

Is there a way to do that without having to put a before_filter on every controller, which is kinda messy ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this to your Home Controller, to skip authentication on all actions on your home controller.

```
skip_before_filter authenticate_user!
```

Comment: brettish answered the same, so i picked this because it was answered earlied. Thanks to everyone guys !

Answer (score 2):

Put the before_filter in the application_controller.  All your other controllers should extend this one (assuming a normal rails setup) and thus inherit the behavior.

Then, put the following in any controller where you want to skip the before filter:

```
skip_before_filter :authenticate_user!, :only => [:new, :create]
```

The :only option is, well, optional.  Use it specify which methods skip the before filter.  If you don't have the :only, then the entire controller will skip the before_filter.

Comment: As i specify in my question, i do not want to put code to every controller. Also, i don't like the blacklisting approach, that is why i ask about whitelisting

Comment: You don't need to but the before_filter in all the controllers, only the application_controller which should be the base controller for all other controllers.  However, the skip_before_filter will need to go into whatever controllers you want to skip.  Also, what about the approach I suggested is blacklisting?

Comment: i see yes, that is reasonable.